# Polymer 1.0: How to style <paper-ripple> color inside <paper-tab> element?

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have an element, let's call it `x-foo`. Inside `x-foo`, I am using `<paper-tabs>`.

## Question

> **How do I change the `<paper-tabs>` ripple color from (the default) `yellow` to `white`**?

#### Bar color is exposed. But not ripple color.

[Here is the documentation I followed to change the bar color](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#xscope-styling-details). The problem is that [the element documentation at the bottom of this page](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-tabs) does not explain or expose the ripple color in the same way.

#### Code

Here is what I have working so far. And what I tried that is not working.

```
:host {
  --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: var(--default-primary-color); /* Works */
  --paper-ripple-color: white; /* Does not work */
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My tip for you is to always check the source code for that [element](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-tabs/) and then you can see how it was structured :) There you can find the `css var` for setting the "ripple" effect color.
The var name is `--paper-tab-ink`
You can see the reference for that `css var`  [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-tabs/blob/master/paper-tab.html#L36)

[polymer](/questions/tagged/polymer) [polymer1.0](/questions/tagged/polymer1.0) [paper-tabs](/questions/tagged/paper-tabs)

Answer (score 5):

Here is what worked for me.

```
<style>
  :host {
    --paper-tab-ink: var(--accent-color);
  }
  paper-tabs {
    --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: var(--accent-color);
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [/deep/](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#xscope-styling) combinator to pierce the shadow DOM, combined with #ink to select for the ripple color.

Here's an example with a white ripple: https://jsbin.com/jiqebamire/edit?html,output

Comment: `/deep/`, `::shadow` and other piercing combinators are deprecated, so stick with either `style-modules` or `css mixins`.